# Winforms, Scintilla - Saving shortcut inserts 's' letter to editor

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcut, scintilla

I write small app for editing sql procedures and use great [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) code-editor control. I defined a Ctrl+S shortcut for saving files:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
    {
            saveToolStripButton_Click(this.saveToolStripButton, null);
    }
    else if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.O))
            openToolStripButton_Click(this.openToolStripButton, null);
    else if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N))
            newToolStripButton_Click(this.newToolStripButton, null);
    else if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.W))
    {
            if (this.tabControl2.SelectedTab != null)
                    (this.tabControl2.SelectedTab as WorkspaceControl).closeSelectedFile();
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

When I'm just resaving oldfile its all ok, but when its new file - after SaveFileDialog is closed and file saved - letter 's' is added to the end of my editor. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "s" is being added because `base.ProcessCmdKey` is being called even when it's not needed.

If you want to prevent further processing of the keystroke, just make sure you return `true` wherever appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! So simple and so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `key_down` event of scintilla control:

```
    private void scintilla_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && e.Control)
        {
            // Saving ...
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```